# Как случайно не удалить базу данных?

Tags: php, mysql

Как правильно делать запрос, чтобы не удалить базу данных?
Слышал, некоторые умудряются с помощью ошибочного запроса удалить базу данных, это как так?

Comment: Не делать ошибочных запросов, очевидно :)

Comment: При любом раскладе у вас должна быть резервная копия, да и случайно удалить бд довольно сложно

Comment: Ограничьте себя правами) Чтобы даже при желании не удалось удалить

Comment: Мне кажется автор пытается узнать про sql-инъекции.

Comment: Да, это как то связано с sql-инъекцииями

Comment: @Anatolio Тогда вопрос особого смысла не имеет. С помощью SQL-инъекций можно сделать что угодно, включая получение полного контроля над атакуемой системой. Хотя конечно зависит от нюансов конкретного подверженного инъекции кода и общих настроек системы и php. Единственное что надо делать - это писать код вообще не подверженный инъекциям, а для этого достаточно не подставлять _никогда_ и никаких переменных в запрос, а использовать подготавливаемые выражения. http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php А от самого запроса это никак не зависит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Целиком всю БД убить затруднительно, если конечно не пытаться править системные таблицы. Вот с update и delete надо быть аккуратным. Я предпочитаю всегда перед такими операциями писать select который выведет что именно будет впоследствии удалено или изменено. И когда select возвращает действительно то, что я собираюсь менять, то заменой нескольких слов изменяю его на update/delete.

В особо тяжелых случаях я явно начинаю транзакцию перед изменением, меняю и проверяю запросом то ли получилось. Если результат устраивает даю commit.

Кроме того, помимо наличия бекапов у меня под руками обычно есть отдельная (возможно не полная) копия БД на которой идет отладка кода.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте пользователя, у которого нет разрешения на удаление баз данных. Войдите в систему как этот пользователь, когда вы делаете не административные вещи, такие как запросы.

Другой вариант-переключиться на [архивный движок](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/archive-storage-engine.html) для исторических таблиц.

Это предотвратит любые действия по удалению или обновлению таблицы, а также сжатие данных. Один (основной) недостаток этого подхода заключается в том, что нельзя индексировать столбцы в таблице.